# Get report on page controls in apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Application Express 4.2.

Is there a way to get properties of controls (select list, display only, button, ...) to review all at the same time, instead of opening one control at a time?

I've checked documentations, as well tried searching (Oracle apex documentation / report / document controls) with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Page Specific Utilities displayed on the right side of the Utilities page. These utilities can be used to view component reports across pages in an application and by component type, including page items.

[image]

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35125/GUID-3BABAF0B-CC8E-4BEE-991F-94F0075ED5F9.htm#GUID-F307198E-AA9C-44EF-A0E6-2809C0442F64